How to use C# interface with DLLImport?
I'm new to C# and I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to use an interface in conjunction with DLL import? I need to accomplish something along the lines of the example code below? If not an interface perhaps an abstract class? TIA
public interface IntDll {

    internal static extern void Func();
}

public class TestDll1 : IntDll {

    [DllImport("Dll1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern void Func();
}

public class TestDll2 : IntDll {

    [DllImport("Dll2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern void Func();
}

public class Test {

    public Test() {

        IntDll intDll1 = new TestDll1();

        intDll1.Func();

        IntDll intDll2 = new TestDll2();

        intDll2.Func();
    }
}


With C#11 (.NET 7) you can define static interface members:
public interface IntDll {
    abstract static void Func();
}

public class TestDll1 : IntDll {

    [DllImport("Dll1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void Func();
}

The way to use it is in generic methods that are constrained on T being IntDll:
void Main() {
    Test<TestDll1>();
}

public void Test<T>()
where T : IntDll {
    T.Func();
}


Interfaces can't define static members, but you can call a static member from an instance member in a class
public interface IntDll
{
    void Func();
}

public class TestDll1 : IntDll
{
    public void Func() => Func1();
    [DllImport("Dll1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern void Func1();
}

To answer your question possible to use an interface in conjunction with DLL import? - No, because dll import must be static extern and you can't define a static member in an interface. If you were hoping to force the implementing class to only use an extern function, no, not with an interface.

Thanks that answers the question but... "I need to accomplish something along the lines of the example code"

What are your constraints? Your sample code works with this method. If you want to coerce the implementer to use a dllimport, you can't. An interface isn't designed for that.
